# How can I make matzo meal and matzo farfel?

Tags: jewish-cuisine, passover

I have a surplus of matzo this year thanks to Costco, and I assume I can crank out my own matzo meal and matzo farfel at home from whole matzo.

Has anyone done this?  Should I just put the matzo in a food processor to make the matzo meal until it looks right?

What about the matzo farfel?  Should I just smash up whole matzo with a meat tenderizing mallet in a bag or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Sassy Radish](http://www.sassyradish.com/2012/04/homemade-matzo-meal/), yes, you can make your own matzo meal by the obvious method of putting some crumbled matzo sheets into the food processor.   She notes that you will get about 1/2 cup from two sheets.

Farfel can be made simply by breaking the matzo into appropriately sized pieces.  [This site](http://suite101.com/article/make-matzah-meal-farfel-cake-meal-with-leftover-passover-matzah-a225229) explains that it is easiest to do it by hand to get the uniform size.  [About.com's Kosher Food section](http://kosherfood.about.com/od/glossaryofjewishfoods/g/farfel.htm) even says that is all farfel is: broken up matzo.

Comment: I just crushed my own matzo farfel; and some notes for others:  I got one cup of useful pieces from 2 1/2 pieces of matzo.  I was able to extract most of the crumbs that were too fine by the fact that they settled to the bottom of the bowl and carefully removing the larger pieces.  I put aside the crumbs for recipes that call for matzo meal.

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that many recipes that call for matzo farfel usually call for soaking it in hot water.  If you add the hot water first before breaking up the whole matzo, it should prevent finer dust from being created.  So follow these instructions:

For each cup of matzo farfel called for in the recipe, use two pieces of matzo.  Add the hot water as called for in the recipe to the whole matzo, then break up into about 1/2 pinky fingernail sized pieces.

Matzo meal can be created just by putting dry matzo in a food processor until the consistency of cornmeal or flour.